# Problems using Primefaces chart

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, primefaces

Well, i'm using primefaces + jsf + bootstrap. So i have a jquery 2.1 imported in my page and i have jquery-primefaces too.

Even now i didn't have problem with this 2 jquery version in same page but now that i'm trying to use p:chart i got error:

```
Cannot read property 'LinearAxisRenderer' of undefined
```

I discovery that if i put this is my "main.js" the chart works:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

But i'm using AdminLTE Bootstrap Theme: https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html and when i put "jquery.noConflict()" all peaces that have jquery in this theme stop to work.

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: what if you just remove the manually added jquery?

Comment: As i said the manually Jquery is for admin LTE bootstrap theme

Comment: As I asked, does it work if you remove it, since there already is a jquery in PrimeFaces, but if you don't want to try, good luckl

Comment: If i remove jquery 2.1 it works , but i can't do it because i need jquery 2.1 to my bootstrap works.

Comment: PrimeFaces has jquery 2.1 afaik. What errors do you get in Bootstrap then?

Comment: Hmmm no, PrimeFaces has 1.11.3, I can't think of any easy solution then

Comment: Yeah, primefaces use 1.11.3 and Admin LTE Bootstrap uses Jquery 2.1. I don't know what can i do to solve this. it's possible ?

Comment: Did you manually include a js file for the chart? E.g. to use additional jqplot functionality?

Comment: NO, i'm using the jquery native from primefaces.